# Can't finish regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

Need to fix regular expresion to match any of size combinations (**width x height x depth 'radius**):
e.g.
`'100`
`100` or `100'100`
`100x100` or `100x100'100`
`100x100x100` or `100x100x100'100`

```java
    checkField = "x1";
    String r = "\\d{0,4}(x\\d{1,4}){0,2}('\\d{1,4})?";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(checkField);
    String a = String.valueOf(m.matches());
    if (m.matches()) {
        infoBox(checkField, a);
    } else {
        errorBox(checkField, a);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
"^(\\d{1,4}(x\\d{1,4}){0,2})?('\\d{1,4})?$"
```

The expression accept an (optional) string of the form AxBxC (with 1, 2 or 3 coordinates) and followed by an optional string of the form 'D.

Since both strings are optional, you should also check that the string is not empty.

Comment: yeah, but then i couldn't type `'1` because before `'` i'll need number too!

Comment: I think you should give a more complete explanation of what you want to achieve, otherwise I can correct that for matching also '1, but I think that would not be enough.

Comment: i need that i can place 1 or all sizes for item - Width, height, depth & radius...
But item can be only with width and height (`1x1`) or only depth (`1`) or only radius (`'1`) so minor string must be `number` or `'radius` and largest `width x height x depth ' radius`

Comment: Thank you and, but i didn't understood how you did that, why now is everything correct? I see difference, but simply can't understand why begin of the line and end of the line did this regex correct!
Would apprecieate ur explain!